# What is my error in using a String in the case method

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I am trying to use the `Scanner` to hold a`String` for the variable "how", and if "how" = yes then execute. the 'yes' case and if 'no' execute the 'no' case this is all inside the else statement from the first question

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you wanna make android apps");
        System.out.println("Yes or no ?");
        String copy=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(copy);

        if(copy.equals("yes")) {
            System.out.println("you should continue java");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Do you wanna make iso apps");
            System.out.println("yes or no");
            String how = null;
            switch(how.toLowerCase()){
                case "yes" :
                    System.out.println("test worked");
                    break;
                case "no":
                    System.out.println("test worked 2");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you forget something `String how=input.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String how = null;
 switch(how.toLowerCase()) //here you are trying to convert null value
```

The above statement is trying to convert `null` value to lowercase.

Assign the value to

```
String how = input.nextLine();
```

Hope this solves your issue..

Answer (score 0):

Change `String how = null;` to `String how = input.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Try {
private enum how_string { yes,no};
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("hello world");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Do you wanna make android apps");
 System.out.println("Yes or no ?");
 String copy=input.nextLine();
 System.out.println(copy);
 if(copy.equals("yes")){
     System.out.println("you should continue java");





 }else{

 System.out.println("Do you wanna make iso apps");
 System.out.println("yes or no");
 String how=input.nextLine();
 how_string p = how_string.valueOf(how.toLowerCase());
 switch(p){

 case yes :System.out.println("test worked");
 break;
 case no :System.out.println("test worked 2");
 break;


 }


  }
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like your `String copy=input.nextLine();`

You need to change `String how  = null;` to `String how = input.nextLine();`

And for your first if else, you better change

```
copy.equals("yes")
```

to

`copy.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")`